# How to Overlay Featured Image with Post Title and Excerpt

Tags: css, wordpress, css-grid

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, I'm a beginning HTML and CSS user. I am working with Wordpress.org. The thing is, I'm creating a page with a post grid. I would like the title and excerpt of those posts to overlay the featured image. Something like this, although the extract is missing in this example:

[Post-Grid-Colums](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybiBD.jpg)

I'd like to use custom CSS for this, but I don't know how. So far I've been working with a child theme to change fonts and colors, nothing more. The publication grid would have two columns in which the dimensions of all the images would be identical. I am using the "query loop" block. I would really appreciate any help you could give me!! Thanks in advance!

I couldn't come up with the right CSS code to achieve the effect I want.

Comment: Start with a tutorial [like this](https://imagekit.io/blog/css-image-overlay/).

Answer (score 1):

The key is to use `position: relative` on the element which represents a single post, and the use `position: absolute` on the text to take it out of the normal flow (superimpose it), and position it at the bottom of the post element.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.my-post-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  gap: 1em;

  > div {
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);

    > img {
      display: block;
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    > div {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 0 1em;
      color: white;
      background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(0 0 0 / 0) 0%, rgba(0 0 0 / 0.8) 100%);
      text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;

      > h3 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-post-grid">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/98/400/225">
    <div>
      <h3>Title One</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut molestie enim at ipsum maximus ultrices.</p>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/197/400/225">
    <div>
      <h3>Title Two</h3>
      <p>Suspendisse vel lectus fringilla, convallis ex ut, porttitor tortor. Mauris ut sem vitae quam consectetur mattis nec non ante.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. The only drawback I find is that, if I'm not mistaken, this code would affect the way all posts are displayed each time a grid is generated. And I would like different layouts for each page. But again, I may be wrong, since I am a beginner in the use of HTML and CSS.

Comment: The thing is, apart from what I just said, I need a page of latest posts that automatically refreshes each time there is a new one so that the most recent ones can be seen. And I think that code would be for a static page, so to speak. But again, it's quite possible that I'm wrong in my statements because I'm just starting to design using code.

Comment: You say you’ve got a child theme, which is great, but what’s it a child of? What’s the name of the parent theme? You also say you are using the **query loop** block. I’d suggest using the **latest posts** block instead, because it has a grid layout and options to select the posts you’d typically want to display. If you assign it a custom class name in the "Advanced" section of the sidebar, you can write CSS specific to that class.

Comment: I didn't know it was necessary to specify the parent theme, that's why I didn't do it since it didn't seem substantial to me since the change I want to make should be able to be made in any theme. Regarding the query loop block, I chose it because it has more customization options. On the other hand, this block has an "Advanced" section to introduce the custom CSS and I have done so, but it has not worked. Thank you for your collaboration.